# installed python module in raspbian jessie will not work in python script

Tags: python-3.x, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I'm pretty new to Python and programming in general. I'm attempting to use the forecastio module in a Python script on my `Raspberry Pi`. Its running `Raspbian Jesse`. I've installed the module like so:

```
sudo pip install python-forecastio
```

the installation was successful, but whenever I attempt to use the module in my script (`import forecastio`) none of the module methods work. I get this error:

> import forecastio
>
> ImportError: No module named 'forecastio'

I've tried rebooting after the module installation. It seems that Python just isn't recognizing the module. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per default the command `pip` refers to the **python 2.7** version of pip.

If you want to use the `forecastio` module in a **python 3** script, you have to use `pip3` to install it.